# Copy worksheets lost header and footer

Tags: closedxml

My web application use ClosedXML to work with Excel files.

I'm trying to copy worksheet using an Excel template with header and footer, but in the result they don't appear. Only the data and cells appear. I use this method to copy my sheet.

```
IXLWorksheet sheet_new = sheet_old.CopyTo("Sheet_new");
```

Can you help me out?

Answer (score 1):

This has already been fixed on commit 76008. Pick that one from [Source Code](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets) or wait for the next release.